# Cannot connect on itms-services app install

Tags: ios

(First off, I've checked most other stackoverflow pages for answers, and none answer this)

Hi there,

I'm putting an app on my website and am trying to download it onto my iPad. However, whenever I try and do this, I get an error:

Cannot connect to

My code is as follows:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://website.com/app.plist">Install</a> (Names have been replaced for privacy)
```

However, I just can't get it to work. Does anyone have an answer to this?

Comment: Try going to the url (https://website.com/app.plist) in Safari on the device and see what it says.

Comment: That comes up with a bunch of code